# The system cannot find the file specied

Tags: android, jar, compiler-errors

I have an issue in which I can't run my app because there's an error `java.io.FileNotFoundException` but the file exists in the libs.

Here's the error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\AndroidProjects\TestApp\app\httpclient-4-1-3.jar (The system cannot find the file specied)
```

Comment: That file may exist in the libs, but that path isn't to the libs folder, so it appears you compiled that jar file incorrectly

Comment: I show it to the explorer to check if the jar file actually exists and it does.

Comment: Can you please share your build.gradle and perhaps a screeenshot of that referenced folder?